# Is every harmonic function of two variables in a disc indefinitely differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Because every harmonic function of two variables in a disc is the real part of
a holomorphic function in that disc, so every harmonic function of two variables in a disc is indefinitely differentiable, isn't it?

Comment: Certainly, yes.

Comment: every real harmonic function